# Single like count per user

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to achieve a custom like button with an output of the number of 'likes' to display once the user has clicked the button.

**Ideal User Case flow:**

Step 1: [USER] - User clicks on 'custom' like button 
Step 2: [SYSTEM] - System displays the number of current likes. 
Step 3: [USER] - User attempts to like button again in the one sitting. 
Step 4: [SYSTEM] - System will not take affect.

**Problem:**

Unfortunately, at this current time, this is actionable as many times as the user likes. A single user can like a page 10 times if they wanted during a single visit.

**Current code:**

HTML

```
<div id="like">

    <input type="image" src="images/love.png" alt="Like" title="Like" width= "34" height="33" id="heart" onClick="onClick()">
    <div>
        <span id="output"></span>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#like {
    margin: 26px 30px 0px 0px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse 
{
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
    to { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        opacity: 1.0;
    }
}

#heart:hover 
{ 
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2; 
}

#output
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 7px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    float: right;
    align-content: center;          
}
```

Javascript

```
// Heart Like counts
var clicks = 50;
function onClick() 
{
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a flag to see if they've clicked already. Assuming you're storing this server side, you can also just set the flag once you restore the data to achieve consistent behavior across loads.

```
var clicks = 50;
var hasClicked = false;

    function onClick() 
    {
        if(!hasClicked)
        {
           clicks += 1;
           document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = clicks;
           hasClicked = true;
        }

    };
```

Comment: Thanks Dylan.  "If" statement of course! Works like a charm. My site is in development. I will be storing the data at a later stage.